# App rejected - your app crashes on iPad running iOS 9.3.2 when we: - Launch the app

Tags: ios, swift

I submitted my app for approval and it was rejected with the message:

"Performance - 2.4.1

Your app crashes on iPad running iOS 9.3.2 when we: - Launch the app"

I have an iPad running 9.3.2 but I have been unable to re-create. Apple attached two crash logs as well. Below is one of the crash logs. I deleted the bottom portion of the crash log as it went over the character limit.

I would greatly appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction on understanding what this crash log is telling me. Thank you!

Below is one of the crash logs from apple:

```
Incident Identifier: 7A1BA9A3-0818-4273-B7D6-61D8BC26CD5C
CrashReporter Key:   3468d98e3e8b6cebaa2f0ba50993f8d4768ac7cc
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             myApp [8280]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/26B6E5B0-D430-47CB-9BC2-BA8AE21ACA78/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:          com.myname.myApp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-07-11 11:54:41.41 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-07-11 11:54:38.38 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010005ce00
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myApp                           0x000000010005ce00 0x100008000 + 347648
1   myApp                           0x0000000100123cc0 0x100008000 + 1162432
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd4bc 0x180edc000 + 5308
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd47c 0x180edc000 + 5244
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ee2b84 0x180edc000 + 27524
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181448d50 0x181368000 + 920912
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181446bb8 0x181368000 + 912312
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181370c50 0x181368000 + 35920
8   GraphicsServices                0x0000000182c58088 0x182c4c000 + 49288
9   UIKit                           0x0000000186652088 0x1865d4000 + 516232
10  myApp                           0x0000000100015948 0x100008000 + 55624
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180f0e8b8 0x180f0c000 + 10424

Activity ID:             0x00000000000f2994
Activity Name:           starting resolver activity
Activity Image Path:     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
Activity Image UUID:     A8E4200A-ECC7-3E56-A845-8A0E9CB4A6F0
Activity Offset:         0x0003333c
Activity Running Time:   2.533887 sec

Trace Messages (reverse chronological seconds):
0.834274     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
0.836194     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
0.836235     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b1951c TCP Conn 0x15f75d860 started
1.184833     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.213000     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.231657     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.232337     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.232471     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b1951c TCP Conn 0x15f6f88a0 started
1.236961     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.237576     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.310092     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.310789     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.310833     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b1951c TCP Conn 0x16112e3a0 started
1.557088     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.559459     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.658670     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.659894     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
1.661243     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
2.483303     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
2.484267     CFNetwork                  0x0000000202b49da8 Format not found
2.484332     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b1951c TCP Conn 0x161109d60 started
2.487436     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b73e5c Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
2.487436     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b73e28 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
2.487436     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181bc5e50 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
2.503853     libsystem_network.dylib    0x0000000202175da8 Format not found
2.505674     libsystem_network.dylib    0x0000000202175da8 Format not found
2.507504     libsystem_network.dylib    0x0000000202175da8 Format not found
2.508164     libsystem_network.dylib    0x0000000202175da8 Format not found



Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102d4d8 0x181010000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ef07d8 0x180edc000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edf648 0x180edc000 + 13896

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102bf6c 0x181010000 + 114540
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810fa39c 0x1810f4000 + 25500
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810fa57c 0x1810f4000 + 25980
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180b03780 0x180af0000 + 79744
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180b06110 0x180af0000 + 90384
5   myApp                           0x0000000100165c7c 0x100008000 + 1432700
6   myApp                           0x000000010015c774 0x100008000 + 1394548
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd4bc 0x180edc000 + 5308
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd47c 0x180edc000 + 5244
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180eeb914 0x180edc000 + 63764
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180eeb0b0 0x180edc000 + 61616
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5470 0x1810f4000 + 5232
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.google.gmp.measurement.worker
Thread 8:
0   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x0000000180e99f04 0x180e80000 + 106244
1   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x0000000180ebaa2c 0x180e80000 + 240172
2   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x0000000180ebbd48 0x180e80000 + 245064
3   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x0000000180eaf014 0x180e80000 + 192532
4   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x0000000180eaf2cc 0x180e80000 + 193228
5   Security                        0x00000001818cee8c 0x181888000 + 290444
6   Security                        0x00000001818c2a8c 0x181888000 + 240268
7   Security                        0x00000001818cf918 0x181888000 + 293144
8   Security                        0x00000001818c2140 0x181888000 + 237888
9   myApp                           0x0000000100164e44 0x100008000 + 1429060
10  myApp                           0x0000000100165f20 0x100008000 + 1433376
11  myApp                           0x0000000100165dec 0x100008000 + 1433068
12  myApp                           0x0000000100165af8 0x100008000 + 1432312
13  myApp                           0x000000010015ab9c 0x100008000 + 1387420
14  myApp                           0x00000001000864b8 0x100008000 + 517304
15  myApp                           0x000000010008db8c 0x100008000 + 547724
16  myApp                           0x000000010008c5b4 0x100008000 + 542132
17  myApp                           0x0000000100074128 0x100008000 + 442664
18  myApp                           0x000000010008ba10 0x100008000 + 539152
19  myApp                           0x0000000100088e7c 0x100008000 + 527996
20  myApp                           0x0000000100088920 0x100008000 + 526624
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd47c 0x180edc000 + 5244
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ede2c0 0x180edc000 + 8896
23  myApp                           0x00000001000881a4 0x100008000 + 524708
24  myApp                           0x0000000100087f98 0x100008000 + 524184
25  myApp                           0x0000000100098e40 0x100008000 + 593472
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd4bc 0x180edc000 + 5308
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180edd47c 0x180edc000 + 5244
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ee94c0 0x180edc000 + 54464
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ee0f80 0x180edc000 + 20352
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180eeb390 0x180edc000 + 62352
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180eeb0b0 0x180edc000 + 61616
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5470 0x1810f4000 + 5232
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102cb48 0x181010000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5530 0x1810f4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5020 0x1810f4000 + 4128

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181010fd8 0x181010000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181010e54 0x181010000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181448c60 0x181368000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181446964 0x181368000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181370c50 0x181368000 + 35920
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181af1c68 0x181a44000 + 711784
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181e67e4c 0x181d74000 + 998988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f7b28 0x1810f4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f7a8c 0x1810f4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5028 0x1810f4000 + 4136

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018102c344 0x181010000 + 115524
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018144f1c8 0x181368000 + 946632
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f7b28 0x1810f4000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f7a8c 0x1810f4000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5028 0x1810f4000 + 4136

Thread 14 name:  com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181010fd8 0x181010000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181010e54 0x181010000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181448c60 0x181368000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181446964 0x181368000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181370c50 0x181368000 + 35920
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181d80cfc 0x181d74000 + 52476
6   myApp                           0x00000001001389b4 0x100008000 + 1247668
7   Foundation                      0x0000000181e67e4c 0x181d74000 + 998988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f7b28 0x1810f4000 + 15144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f7a8c 0x1810f4000 + 14988
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001810f5028 0x1810f4000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000100975400   x1: 0x00000001810ee8f4   x2: 0x0000000161147180   x3: 0x0000000000000003
    x4: 0x000000016fdf68bc   x5: 0x0000000180aed3e8   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000900
    x8: 0x0000000100975408   x9: 0x0000000000004000  x10: 0x0000000161148000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000161144000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000181058168  x17: 0x000000018138fde8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016116ecc0
   x20: 0x000000016116e9f0  x21: 0x000000016114a450  x22: 0x000000015f5e2790  x23: 0x000000018703eeea
   x24: 0x000000015f5f5a60  x25: 0x0000000000000003  x26: 0x000000016116ece0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001002ad000  fp: 0x000000016fdf6ba0   lr: 0x000000010005ce00
    sp: 0x000000016fdf6a40   pc: 0x000000010005ce00 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images:
0x100008000 - 0x100233fff myApp arm64  <7f2d1222bb443384bbcac3d1a81193bf> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/26B6E5B0-D430-47CB-9BC2-BA8AE21ACA78/myApp.app/myApp
0x10030c000 - 0x10033bfff JSQMessagesViewController arm64  <91e16e997aef33e7b5f9fd71ce475c4e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/26B6E5B0-D430-47CB-9BC2-BA8AE21ACA78/myApp.app/Frameworks/JSQMessagesViewController.framework/JSQ
```

Comment: If you import this log into Xcode on the same machine that has the archive you submitted to Apple, Xcode should be able to symbolicate this log (i.e., translate memory addresses back to method names).

Comment: ...or so I heard (never had to do it myself)

Comment: @NicolasMiari thanks for the response! I was able to import the crash log apple sent me into Xcode in the devices window. I right clicked on the log and selected resymbolicate. The above log is the output.

Comment: Weird. I'm no crash log expert, but was expected way more symbols. See this article, for example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: Your crash log looks like it's in the cryptic "base address + offset" format. It doesn't seem obvious in which method it is crashing.

Comment: Thank you I will read this!

Comment: For resimbolication process you need to have the original .xarchive in you xcode